# Why do I get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: createImageUsingNativeSize error in 1.8.0_45

Tags: java, macos, java-8

This code that was used in some circumstances for dealing with single images dragged and drop from certain webbrowsers (firefox) gave no issues in 1.8.0_25

```
image  = (Image) trans.getTransferData("image/x-java-image;class=java.awt.Image");
```

but now in 1.8.0_45 causing

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: createImageUsingNativeSize
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CDataTransferer.getImageForByteStream(Native Method)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CDataTransferer.platformImageBytesToImage(CDataTransferer.java:238)
at sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.translateBytes(DataTransferer.java:1659)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CDataTransferer.translateBytes(CDataTransferer.java:142)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.getTransferData(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:269)
at sun.awt.datatransfer.TransferableProxy.getTransferData(TransferableProxy.java:73)
at java.awt.dnd.DropTargetContext$TransferableProxy.getTransferData(DropTargetContext.java:376)
at com.jthink.jaikoz.draganddrop.ImageHandler.createImageCell(ImageHandler.java:30)
```

Is this a bug in the new version of OSX Java or am I simply doing something wrong, is there a simple workaround ?

Paul

Comment: What is the output when you type _java -version_ for the two respective installations?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the jdk. See [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8077016?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:worklog-tabpanel#issue-tabs)

Comment: And the fix is targeted for version 9. Looks like you're going to wait.

Comment: @Jens thanks, how the hell did a bug that serious creep in there !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was eventually fixed in JDK1.8.0_66, see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8037371

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to JDK 1.8.0_31 fixes the issue for me.

I call the following "jdk8" script with ". jdk8"

```
version=1.8.0_31
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $version)
```

and get

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

and the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: createImageUsingNativeSize error in 1.8.0_45 is gone